Upload Button Not Clickable in Popup Form
I'm working on a web project where I have a popup form for uploading images and adding game names. Everything seems to be in place, but the upload button in the popup form isn't clickable.
Does anyone have suggestions on why the button might not be clickable and how to resolve this issue?


document.getElementById('addMiniCardBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  showPopupForm();
});

document.querySelector('.close-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  hidePopupForm();
});

document.getElementById('uploadForm').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData(this);

  fetch('upload_card.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.success) {
        var card = data.card;
        var miniCardContainer = document.getElementById('miniCardContainer');
        var miniCard = document.createElement('div');
        miniCard.className = 'mini-card';
        miniCard.innerHTML = `
        <img src="${card.image_path}" alt="${card.game_name}">
        <div class="game-names">${card.game_name}</div>
        <img src="images/trashcan.png" class="delete-icon" alt="Delete" onclick="deleteMiniCard(this, '${card.id}')">
      `;
        miniCardContainer.appendChild(miniCard);
        hidePopupForm();
      } else {
        alert(data.message);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
<div class="popup-form" id="popupForm">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <form id="uploadForm" action="upload_card.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file">Select Image:</label>
      <input type="file" id="gameImageFile" name="file" accept="image/*" required>
      <label for="gameName">Game Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="gameName" name="gameName" required>
      <button type="submit" id="uploadButton">Upload</button>
      <button type="button" class="close-btn" onclick="hidePopupForm()">Close</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>




It's not clear exactly what happens when you do showPopupForm - many dialog handlers will remove the dialog HTML from where you place it and put it at the root of body, so that it's not affected by any other styling such as overflow:hidden  - which could be affecting your event handlers.

I created a snippet from your code where, once you've filled in the required form fields, the Upload button appears to work absolutely fine. I'd suggest checking the console in your browser to diagnose the errors first.

Or your code could be running before the elements exist.  See this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element-if-i  (but I think that might give an error rather than be "not clickable").  This would also explain why it works in the snippet provided - as that adds the JS at the end.

Does "not clickable" mean it's disabled, or just doesn't do what you want / does nothing when you do click it?   Have you checked the console for errors?
